# Mercurial: Multiple Change sets at once?

Tags: mercurial, perforce

Before, when I was using perforce, I could work on multiple bugs at once as long as the code did not affect the same files, by having multiple change sets open at once.

Changeset 1:

---

- A.txt
- B.txt
- C.txt

Changeset 2:

---

- D.txt
- E.txt
- F.txt

I could submit changeset 2 to the repository without submitting changeset 1 (because it's still in progress)

Is this possible with Mercurial? other than doing each file as a separate commit?

Answer (score 3):

You can always just do: `hg commit D.txt E.txt F.txt` to commit just those files which will leave A.txt, B.txt, and C.txt uncommited.  Using the `-I` option to commit lets you do those with patterns if they're, for example, in a common directory: `hg commit -I 'dir1/**'`

Answer (score 2):

You can have two separate branches (working copies) and make one change in and the other in the other.  That's one way.

Another is to use [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension).  You can use `qpush --move` to change the order of changesets if they have no dependencies on one another, so you can then use `qfinish` to 'commit' the first changeset that's ready.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually hold changesets "open" in Mercurial.

Either you've committed your changes, or you haven't.

You can, however, have multiple files with uncommitted changes, and only commit a few of them. It is even possible to commit parts of files, chunks, instead of the whole file.

If I was to do what you're asking I would simply make another clone locally from my first one, and work on the two different fixes in two different working folders. Then I have all the freedom I need to combine the two (push/pull locally), push to the server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Mercurial, cloning is a cheap operation when done locally.  Just clone the repository for each thing you are working on.  Push back to the main repository as each thing is ready:

```
hg clone http://project project
hg clone project project-bugfix   // uses hardlinks and is inexpensive.
hg clone project project-feature
<edit bugfix and feature as needed>
```

But remember that the default push location is the project cloned from, so you'll either need to edit .hg\hgrc's default push path for the "project" clones, or make sure to `hg push http://project` from "project-bugfix" and "project-feature" when complete.

Comment: Cloning is cheap yes, but setting up my dev environment is a very expensive process.

Comment: Then I recommend patch queues or named branches.  or use relative instead of hard-coded paths in your projects ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Even if your modifications touches the same file you can select what to include (hunk by hunk). You just have to activate the `record` extension (it's installed by not activated by default).

To activate the record extension, put this in the `[extensions]` section of your `.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
hgext.record=
```

Then to commit, replace `hg commit` by `hg record`. Let's assume your example change sets with a `G.txt` file that have changes for both change sets. Commit with:

```
hg record D.txt E.txt F.txt G.txt
```

Answer questions, for example:

```
2 hunks, 6 lines changed
examine changes to 'D.txt'? [Ynsfdaq?] f     # f for full file (help with ?)
... skipped file E and F
6 hunks, 35 lines changed
examine changes to 'G.txt'? [Ynsfdaq?] y
@@ ... (patch hunk here)
record change 6/16 to 'G.txt'? [Ynsfdaq?] y   # y to include the hunk, n to skip
```